# How to approach complex circular relations between models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to set up a database for my media files, but can't find a way to translate the data to models and useful, but not redundant relationships.

There are Photos and Videos as models on the media side.

```
     class Photo(MediaFile):
        file = UniqueNameImageField(upload_to="photos/")
        preview = UniqueNameImageField(upload_to="previews/", blank=True)
        thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnails/", blank=True)
        mediatype = "photo"
        
    class Video(MediaFile):
        file = UniqueNameFileField(upload_to="videos/")
        preview = UniqueNameFileField(upload_to="previews/", blank=True)    
        thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnails/", blank=True)
        mediatype = "video"
...
```

As Metadata I want to store Persons, Quotes, and Releases (contracts with the appearing person).

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([self.name, "("+str(self.age)+")", self.city])
    
class Release(models.Model):
    person =  models.ForeignKey("Person", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="release_docs/")
        
class Quote(models.Model):
    person =  models.ForeignKey("Person", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    #alternative by-line if it should not be name+age
    alt_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Every Release should be tied to a person.
Every Quote should be tied to a person.

But then every Person, Release, and Quote will be tied to the Photos and Videos.

The tricky part is this: Not every release counts for every photo a person is in, but rather just for a specific set of photos and videos.

Also, quotes don't belong to every photo and video a person appears in, but rather the ones from the day when the person is quoted.

This would bring me to set a many2many relationship between releases and photos/videos and also a many2many relationship between people and photos/videos and also a many2many relationships between quotes and photos/videos...

Now there is a lot of duplication because if a release is tied to a photo it already contains a connection to a person. However, the person object needs a separate relationship to the same photo.

In short, everything is tied to everything, but that leads to duplicated and maybe conflicting information in the DB.

I'm not looking for a solution to this case here, but rather a pointer in the right direction on how to handle these kinds of relations or simplify them. Surely this is not so uncommon. How to approach this / what keyword to look out for?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a m2m relation with an intermediary model between Person and MediaFile. In the intermediary instance you can keep references to quotes and releases, as well as dates and other relevant data. This way Release and Quote would not need to have a direct relation with Person. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Comment: Sounds like this might lead somewhere. You are talking about using the "through=" functionality, right?

Comment: yes, this is what I'm referring to